# I have dict -> pairs = {2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0, 10:0, 11:0, 12:0} trying to change the keys' values with for loop, not working,

Tags: python, simulator, dice

```
import random

pairs = {2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0, 10:0, 11:0, 12:0}

for i in range(0, 1001):

    d1 = random.randrange(0, 7)
    d2 = random.randrange(0, 7)
    summ = d1 + d2
    for k, v in pairs.items():
        if summ == k:
            k[v] += 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "not working" in this case mean? What results are you getting, and what results do you expect?

Comment: I'm sure `randrange(0, 7)` is wrong.

Comment: I expect when summ is equal to the key for ex. summ is 2 then value of the key(2) added with 1 and continue adding until range(1000) reached

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, but what do you get?

Comment: Vladimir Fokow answer worked, thank you !

Comment: You don't need to loop to find the matching key. Just use `if k in pairs:`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to *read and understand* error messages. In this case, you are told directly that the problem is in the line `k[v] += 1`, and that the problem is because it is not possible to subscript like `k[v]`, because `k` is an integer. The reason `k` is an integer is because it is already the key from the dictionary, not the key itself. If you want to assign into a dictionary, you must subscript the dictionary: `pairs[k] += 1`. That said, there is no reason to iterate like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you meant to write was this:

```py
import random

pairs = {2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0, 10:0, 11:0, 12:0}

for i in range(0, 1001):

    d1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    d2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    summ = d1 + d2
    pairs[summ] += 1

print(pairs)
```

I see that you are searching though the `pairs` dict to find the right key which is a strange way to find a key. I now see the reason for that was because you are using `randrange(0, 7)` which produces numbers in the inclusive range of `0..6`. This will mean that `summ` could be `0` or `1` which is not one of the keys contained in `pairs`.

By using `randint(1, 6)` this is a lot more like rolling a pair of dice and gives `summ` in the exact range of the keys you prepared in `pairs`. This allows my version to just register each roll with `pairs[summ] += 1`

Comment: Given that nothing else is done with those values, it might just be: `pairs[random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1, 6)] += 1`

Comment: Yes, that's right, but I left it like this to have some correspondence with the OP's code for easier understanding.

Comment: Please don't answer questions caused by simple typos, and please don't infer questions from "I have this code... it is not working". Yes, I misread at first, but the problem is still clearly a typo. Other issue with writing unnecessarily complex code etc. are off topic here; this is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Not a typo by the OP, but yes, I answered in haste before the OP had stated what was wrong.

Comment: The `k[v]` rather than `pairs[k]` isn't, in your view, a typo? You imagine that there is something here that is likely to help future readers? If the question really is "how do I change the value in a dict associated with a given key, given the key and the (irrelevant) existing value?", then surely there is a different duplicate for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are generating 1000 random dice rolls, then counting them. This can be done efficiently using `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import counter
from random import randint as r

pairs = dict(Counter(r(1, 6) + r(1, 6) for _ in range(1001)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change `k[v] += 1` to `pairs[k] += 1`

`k` is an integer + dictionary key, so the brackets doesn't really make sense in this situation.

You could also just loop through the `keys` because you aren't really using the value in that dict loop

```py
for k in pairs.keys():
    if summ == k:
        pairs[k] += 1
```